# Expose specific element in ShadowDom to external JS using document.getElementById

Tags: web-component, shadow-dom, polymer-2.x, shady-dom

I have a v0/Polymer 1 web component that I am upgrading to v1/Polymer 2. This web component dynamically builds a URI that loads an external JavaScript file. The external JavaScript file runs and loads an `<iframe>` into a `<div>` of my component. This external JS contains `document.getElementById` to load the `<iframe>` into the specified `<div>`.

I have searched and haven't found a way to force the `<div>` element to be exposed/placed in the **shady DOM**. I have read that if I design the component without a **shadow DOM** nothing will be displayed.

Is there anyway I can update this to web components v1/Polymer 2 with the external script (third party) still using `document.getElementbyId` to modify a `<div>` inside the web component?

**UPDATE** 
I have found that I can force webcomponents to use the shadow dom using `<script>window.ShadyDOM = { force: true };</script>` or `<script src="/bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js" shadydom></script>` however I still cannot access the element by ID and I do not want to force all other webcomponents to use the shady DOM. Still looking for possibilities.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I had to do was put a `<slot></slot>` inside my Web Components template. When I declare the custom element, I have to nest a `<div>` inside of it like so: `<custom-element><div></div></custom-element>` which I am doing using `this.appendChild()` where `this` is the custom element. The `<div>` inside my element can now be accessed by `document.getElementById()` once it is assigned an `id` attribute.

Comment: It's a good solution, but note that the element in not really in the shadow dom but rather in the lite dom (and then *inserted* in the shadow dom thanks to <slot>)

Comment: That is correct. I needed a <div> element that could be accessed outside of the web component by third party JS and this is what I had found. I wasn't using <content> in my previous implementation and just (incorrectly) accessing the shadyDOM by ID which you cant do with the shadowDom :)